# Matplotlib RuntimeError: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS when using MultipleLocator

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am plotting a Matplotlib chart with 10000 x axis data points. To avoid the X axis labels overlapping, I have used a Major MultipleLocator of 40 and a minor MultipleLocator of 10. This code works for 1000 data points.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

##generating 1000 data points
years = [i for i in range(1,10000)]
data = np.random.rand(len(years))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (18,6))

ind = np.arange(len(data))

bars1 = ax.bar(ind, data, 
        label='Data')

ax.set_title("Data vs Year")

#Format Y Axis
ax.set_ylabel("Data")
ax.set_ylim((0,1))

#Format X Axis
ax.set_xticks(range(0,len(ind)))
ax.set_xticklabels(years)
ax.set_xlabel("Years")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(40))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d'))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(10))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.xaxis_date()
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

This above chart produces the following error.

```
RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 1102 ticks from -510.0 to 10500.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS
```

Can you please tell me the error in this chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should remove these two lines:

```
ax.set_xticks(range(0,len(ind)))
ax.set_xticklabels(years)
```

These lines set 10000 ticks first. Since you used `ax.xaxis.set_major/minor_locator()`, these two lines are not needed. And then the line `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(10))` will generate 1102 ticks (mticker.Locator.MAXTICKS==1000), so you should change the arg to at least 12 as a result of my testing.

Change arg of `mticker.MultipleLocator()` larger will get fewer ticks.

Despite any reason, if you do need 277 major ticks (40), and 1102 minor ticks (10), you can change the 'MAXTICKS' by `mticker.Locator.MAXTICKS = 2000`